# c from integer to string function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
void to_string(int x)
{
    int value, i = 0;
    char numericalChar[] = "0123456789";
    char *string;
    do
    {
        value = x % 10;
        string[i++] = numericalChar[value];
        x /= 10;
    } while(x >= 0);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

I am trying to write a function that turns an integer into a string. I don't think there is nothing with my logic but I am getting a segfault and my printf() is not printing anything out. I probably missing something obvious. I have been sitting in front of the computer for an hour and still, I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you haven't allocated memory for `string` variable

Comment: `char *string` is a pointer to a char but you have not separated memory so using `string[ix]` is invalid.

Comment: Why not just use `sprintf` or its safer implementations?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you know that there are in fact standard function for this (e.g. `sprintf` - see example below) but just want to write it yourself, right...

In that case:

First of all you need to assign memory to hold the string. Using a char pointer is not enough. You get a seg fault because of that. A uninitialized pointer just points somewhere into memory where you are (most likely) not allowed to write. So when do... it seg faults. In this case just use a short fixed size char array instead.

Second it is much easier just to add each digit to the char `'0'` to get the correct digit. No need for an array as look up table.

Something like:

```
void to_string(int x)
{
    char string[32] = "0";
    if (x > 0)
    {
            char temp[32] = {0};
            int i = 31;

            // Build a temp string from from the end (right to left)
            while(x > 0)
            {
                temp[--i] = '0' + (x % 10);
                x /= 10;
            }

            // Copy the temp string to the target variable
            strcpy(string, &temp[i]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Notice that this code only handles integers greater than or equal to zero. I'll leave negative integers as an exercise.

If you want to use e.g. `sprintf` it's as easy as:

```
int n = 42;
char string[32];
sprintf(string, "%d", n);
printf("%s\n", string);
```

Comment: I actually didn't know there was a standard function to do this. But since I already started I might as well do this way.

Comment: @TheCaptain ahh, I see. In that case you should read about `sprintf` and `snprintf` and use them instead. Don't write your own function when there's already something available. I just thought you were practicing. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html

Answer (score 1):

So as people already commented on your question, you have not allocated space so:

```
char *string;
```

should be

```
char *string = malloc ( sizeof (char) * numberOfDigits);
```

and there is another seg fault that I could not figure out, while I fix it I will give you this:

[itoa solutions](https://github.com/goranvel/KandR/blob/master/ch5/exercises/e5-6/e3-6.c)

Comment: lol, programming in C is nuts, even a simple function requires memory management.

Comment: @TheCaptain ;) that is why I love it :)

Answer (score -3):

```
void to_string(int x) {
   string s = "";
   while(x){
       s += (x % 10) + 48;
       x /= 10;
   }
   printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: your *solution* works?, 
the OP clearly does not answer, read [answer]

Comment: @eyllanesc hey, I am not on my computer every second.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry I thought you were referring to me in the first comment.

Comment: @TheCaptain When a comment is used without the use of the @ it refers to the author of the post, in this case the answer. Please comment where it should be.

Comment: @TheCaptain According to your registration you already have 1 year and 9 months.

Comment: I registered to ask one question and never use it again until a month ago. Anyways what is the point?